# Reachability ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_Reachability.localWiFiRef

Tags: objective-c, duplicates, symbols, reachability

I include "Reachability/Reachability.m"

```
AppDelegate.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Reachability/Reachability.m"

@class ...;

@interface ... : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    ... *viewController;
    Reachability *hostReach;
    NetworkStatus netStatus;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;
@property (nonatomic) NetworkStatus netStatus;
-(void)updateInterfaceWithReachability: (Reachability*) curReach;

@end


AppDelegate.m


#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ...

@synthesize window=_window;
@synthesize navigationController=_navigationController;
@synthesize netStatus;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(reachabilityChanged:) name: kReachabilityChangedNotification object: nil];
    hostReach = [[Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.apple.com"]retain];
    [hostReach startNotifier];
    [self updateInterfaceWithReachability:hostReach];


    // Set the view controller as the window's root view controller and display.
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

and I get an error

```
ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_Reachability.localWiFiRef in /Users/../Documents/../build/.. .build/Debug-iphonesimulator/.. .build/Objects-normal/i386/..ViewController.o and /Users/../Documents/../build/.. .build/Debug-iphonesimulator/.. .build/Objects-normal/i386/..AppDelegate.o

Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

how to solve this problem? and what it might be related?

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same problem because one third-party library ([libPusher](https://github.com/lukeredpath/libPusher/)) I'm using was including Reachability already.

Since that library was pre-compiled, I wasn't sure what to do, but adding only `Reachability.h` to the project (and not `Reachability.m`) worked. That allowed me to import it and use the class but I didn't have the duplicate symbol issue.

Answer (score 2):

You only import header files. Do,

```
#import "Reachability/Reachability.h"
```

Comment: then error ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_Reachability.reachabilityRef in /Users/vladimir/Documents/FreeLance/build/FreeLance.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FreeLance.build/Objects-normal/i386/Reachability-6894AC99071B3187.o and /Users/vladimir/Documents/FreeLance/build/FreeLance.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FreeLance.build/Objects-normal/i386/Reachability-A3396D425720E183.o

Comment: Are you using any third party libraries? You might be facing the same problem mentioned [`here`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/asihttprequest/Mx3f__bJ2fw).

Comment: How can I use both ASIHTTPRequest and Reachability? rather than remove one of the libraries

Answer (score 2):

you have to make sure your project folder contains one Reachability.h and one Reachability.m files , ASIHTTPRequest library has both these files in it hence the duplicate symbol error when adding the Reachability library.  after removing the duplicate files do a clean build

Answer (score 0):

1. Removing the reference of reachability.m from the project.
2. Add Framework or files you want (which created this issue).
3. Clean and Build project

It worked for me.

when i tried adding framework in project, and this duplicate issue appeared.